# Stored procedure triggered on insert causes deadlock in transaction

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, deadlock, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to debug a deadlock that happens when a stored procedure is triggered inside a transaction. Table and trigger definitions are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
  b varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  d date NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; //

CREATE PROCEDURE CheckNoDuplicates (new_id int(11), new_b varchar(10), new_d date)
BEGIN
  DECLARE existingId INT(11);

  SELECT id INTO existingId
  FROM a
  WHERE new_b = b
      AND d IS NOT NULL AND new_d IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(d) = YEAR(new_d)
        OR d IS NULL AND new_d IS NULL
       AND id <> new_id;

  IF existingId IS NOT NULL THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '23000';
  END IF;
END //

CREATE TRIGGER NoDuplicateOnInsert BEFORE INSERT ON a
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    CALL CheckNoDuplicates(NEW.id, NEW.b, NEW.d);
  END //

CREATE TRIGGER NoDuplicateOnInsert BEFORE UPDATE ON a
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    CALL CheckNoDuplicates(NEW.id, NEW.b, NEW.d);
  END //
```

When two inserts happen at the same time inside a transaction, sometimes they succeed, sometimes they give me back a deadlock (Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction).

If I get rid of the stored procedure, I get no deadlocks anymore.

How are stored procedure executed inside a transaction? 
Is there a better way to keep the constraint I'm trying to get (uniqueness on b and the YEAR of date d)?

Comment: missing an open paren??

Comment: The missin parenthesis was just a typo - I've edited my question to remove the extra paren. The point was about the deadlock though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way to keep the constraint I'm trying to get (uniqueness on b and the YEAR of date d)?

Create virtual generated column which calculates value You'd like to be unique, and create unique secondary index over it.

For more information read [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual / Secondary Indexes and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(b)
```

should help a lot.  This might be even better:

```
INDEX(b, d, id)
```